# Radio button issue

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

So for this class in java, here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class RadioSelection extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private ActionListener action;  
private JButton[][] button;
private JPanel bottomPanel;
private LineBorder lineBorder;

private int randomRowLimit;
private int randomColumnLimit;
private Random random;
private int size;
JLabel label = new JLabel("Select the no. of Grid");
public RadioSelection()
{
    randomRowLimit = 0;
    randomColumnLimit = 0;
    random = new Random();
    size = 0;

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationByPlatform(true);

    lineBorder = new LineBorder(Color.BLUE.darker());


    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    bottomPanel = new JPanel();

    final JRadioButton threeSquareButton = new JRadioButton("3 X 3", false);
    final JRadioButton fourSquareButton = new JRadioButton("4 X 4", false);
    final JRadioButton fiveSquareButton = new JRadioButton("5 X 5", false);

    threeSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);
    fourSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);
    fiveSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);
    label.setFont(null);
    action = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {

            if (ae.getSource() == threeSquareButton)
            {
                remove(bottomPanel);
                bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(3);
                add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            else if (ae.getSource() == fourSquareButton)
            {
                remove(bottomPanel);
                bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(4);
                add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            else if (ae.getSource() == fiveSquareButton)
            {

                remove(bottomPanel);
                bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(5);
                add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }


            invalidate(); // If you are using JDK 1.7 +
            //getContentPane().revalidate(); // if you using JDK 1.6 or lower
              repaint();
          }
      };

    threeSquareButton.addActionListener(action);
    fourSquareButton.addActionListener(action);
    fiveSquareButton.addActionListener(action);

    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(threeSquareButton);
    bg.add(fourSquareButton);
    bg.add(fiveSquareButton);


    topPanel.add(label);
    topPanel.add(threeSquareButton);
    topPanel.add(fourSquareButton);
    topPanel.add(fiveSquareButton);

    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setSize(300, 300);
    //pack();
    setVisible(true);
 }
 private JPanel getCenterPanel(int size)
 {
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size, size));
    button = new JButton[size][size];
    this.size = size;

    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < size; column++)
        {
            button[row][column] = new JButton();
            button[row][column].setBorder(lineBorder);
            button[row][column].setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
            button[row][column].addActionListener(this);
            bottomPanel.add(button[row][column]);
        }
    }

    randomRowLimit = random.nextInt(size);
    randomColumnLimit = random.nextInt(size);
    button[randomRowLimit][randomColumnLimit].setText("mouse");

    return bottomPanel;
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();

    if ((button.getText()).equals("mouse"))
    {
        randomRowLimit = random.nextInt(size);
        randomColumnLimit = random.nextInt(size);
        System.out.println("Row : " + randomRowLimit);
        System.out.println("Column : " + randomColumnLimit);
        button.setText("");
        this.button[randomRowLimit][randomColumnLimit].setText("mouse");            
    }
    else
    {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Catch the mouse!", "Small Game : ",                     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public static void main(String... args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            new RadioSelection();
        }
    });
}
```

}

This one is working but if you notice, I used `invalidate();` here. If it is `revalidate();`, it will not run. However, my concern here is when a radio-button is clicked (e.g 3x3), the button will not show automatically. The frame should be adjusted first before the gird buttons appear. How can I work with this one?

Comment: What/where 3x3 and 4x4 radio buttons?

Comment: did you by any chance forget the homework tag :-)

Comment: Somebody already answered my question.well not sure of his answer,but ill try the code he gives to me,thank you for your time guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your hands on this code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class RadioSelection extends JFrame
{
    private ActionListener action;  
    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    private LineBorder lineBorder ;

    public RadioSelection()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        lineBorder = new LineBorder(Color.BLUE.darker());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        bottomPanel = new JPanel();

        final JRadioButton threeSquareButton = new JRadioButton("3 X 3", false);
        final JRadioButton fourSquareButton = new JRadioButton("4 X 4", false);

        threeSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);
        fourSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);

        action = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (ae.getSource() == threeSquareButton)
                {
                    remove(bottomPanel);
                    bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(3);
                    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == fourSquareButton)
                {
                    remove(bottomPanel);
                    bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(4);
                    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                revalidate(); // If you are using JDK 1.7 +
                // getContentPane().revalidate(); // if you using JDK 1.6 or lower
                repaint();
            }
        };

        threeSquareButton.addActionListener(action);
        fourSquareButton.addActionListener(action);

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(threeSquareButton);
        bg.add(fourSquareButton);

        topPanel.add(threeSquareButton);
        topPanel.add(fourSquareButton);

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getCenterPanel(int size)
    {
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size, size));

        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < size; column++)
            {
                JButton button = new JButton("Button " + row + " " + column);
                button.setBorder(lineBorder);
                button.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
                bottomPanel.add(button);
            }
        }

        return bottomPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new RadioSelection();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output of this :

[image: 3 X 3 MATRIX]  and [image: 4 X 4 MATRIX]

Added this new code to answer a new thing :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class RadioSelection extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private ActionListener action;  
    private JButton[][] button;

    private JPanel bottomPanel;
    private LineBorder lineBorder;

    private int randomRowLimit;
    private int randomColumnLimit;
    private Random random;
    private int size;

    public RadioSelection()
    {
        randomRowLimit = 0;
        randomColumnLimit = 0;
        random = new Random();
        size = 0;

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        lineBorder = new LineBorder(Color.BLUE.darker());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        bottomPanel = new JPanel();

        final JRadioButton threeSquareButton = new JRadioButton("3 X 3", false);
        final JRadioButton fourSquareButton = new JRadioButton("4 X 4", false);
        final JRadioButton fiveSquareButton = new JRadioButton("5 X 5", false);

        threeSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);
        fourSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);
        fiveSquareButton.setBorder(lineBorder);

        action = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (ae.getSource() == threeSquareButton)
                {
                    remove(bottomPanel);
                    bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(3);
                    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == fourSquareButton)
                {
                    remove(bottomPanel);
                    bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(4);
                    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == fiveSquareButton)
                {
                    remove(bottomPanel);
                    bottomPanel = getCenterPanel(5);
                    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }
                revalidate(); // If you are using JDK 1.7 +
                // getContentPane().revalidate(); // if you using JDK 1.6 or lower
                repaint();
            }
        };

        threeSquareButton.addActionListener(action);
        fourSquareButton.addActionListener(action);
        fiveSquareButton.addActionListener(action);

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(threeSquareButton);
        bg.add(fourSquareButton);
        bg.add(fiveSquareButton);

        topPanel.add(threeSquareButton);
        topPanel.add(fourSquareButton);
        topPanel.add(fiveSquareButton);

        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(300, 300);
        //pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getCenterPanel(int size)
    {
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size, size));
        button = new JButton[size][size];
        this.size = size;

        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < size; column++)
            {
                button[row][column] = new JButton();
                button[row][column].setBorder(lineBorder);
                button[row][column].setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
                button[row][column].addActionListener(this);
                bottomPanel.add(button[row][column]);
            }
        }

        randomRowLimit = random.nextInt(size);
        randomColumnLimit = random.nextInt(size);
        button[randomRowLimit][randomColumnLimit].setText("X");

        return bottomPanel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();

        if ((button.getText()).equals("X"))
        {
            randomRowLimit = random.nextInt(size);
            randomColumnLimit = random.nextInt(size);
            System.out.println("Row : " + randomRowLimit);
            System.out.println("Column : " + randomColumnLimit);
            button.setText("");
            this.button[randomRowLimit][randomColumnLimit].setText("X");            
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Click on X Mark to follow it.", "Small Game : ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new RadioSelection();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ,thank you really for this.this is the one i really need. How can i thank you for this.?thank you!!

Comment: @shielomarie : Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: ,for this code,im going to add another radiobutton for 5x5 buttons.really thank you! Heres my smile ^-^

Comment: hehe :-), that is really nice.

Comment: For additional question regarding the codes. For scenario, a radio button is clicked,which is 3x3 then 9 buttons will be shown in the output.if you click a button out of 9 buttons,a message box will appear'catch the mouse!' if you click on the button with x on it, the x will transfer to the other button randomly. Do i make sense here?just want to know if this is possible? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @shielomarie : Please do see this code now is this what you want ?

Comment: You are a genius!this is the one ive been looking for.i dont know how to thank you! Thank u so much!!very much appreciated your effort here coding.thanks!!

Comment: That is really nice of you. Thinking mind is a genius's mind. So even you are a genius too :-) Who knows, what might you will create in future :-)

Comment: sir i cant find how to run this one? revalidate has an underline. :(

Comment: wow.its working.i change the revalidate(); to invalidate();but when i click radiobutton,the buttons wont come out.maybe because the size of the frame is not declared..to be able to see the grid buttons,the user should adjust the side of the frame. isn't it automatic? it shouldbe when a radiobutton is click,(e.g 3x3) 9 buttons will appear even without adjusting the frame.                                .thanks anyway!

Comment: @shielomarie : Please do read the comments in my attached program in my answer, if your `JDK is 1.6 or lower`, then `revalidate()` won't work, you have to use `frameObject.getContentPane().revalidate();`.`revalidate();` works for JDK 1.7 or higher.   How was it working before ? Do try to copy this code again and paste it at your end. It's working fine at my end.

Comment: @shielomarie :  Never use `invalidate()`, it is completely opposite in meaning to `revalidate()`, we use `revalidate()` to undo `invalidate()`. LOL and you are deliberately using `invalidate()`. If nothing works, edit your question with the code you are trying :-)

Comment: @Gagandeep >>invalidate(); here is working sir.. the code you give to me is working,though when a radiobutton is click,the buttons appear if the frame is adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question or the code, but I'd expect to see an ActionListener on the 3x3 button that would create an array of `JRadioButton` instances using a method that's something like this:

```
private JRadioButton [][] createRadioButtonArray(int squareSize) {
    JRadioButton [][] arrayOfButtons = new JRadioButton[squareSize][squareSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < squareSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < squareSize; ++j) {
            arrayOfButtons[i][j] = new JRadioButton("button" + i + "," + j,false);
        }
    }
    return arrayOfButtons;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what im looking for. thank you for your help. Sorry if you cant understand my question im not that really good in english. Uhm whats wih the int square?

Comment: Do you mean "squareSize"?  That's the size of the array: 3 for your 3x3 case; 4 for your 4x4 case; etc.  I'd prefer that you accept the answer to your thanks.

Comment: What are the imports?need for this application?thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not writing your app for you.  You're already importing what you need for this method.

Comment: I know.i mean imports do i have to put


import javax.awt.*;

Comment: I know what you mean.  No, you should not use * in import.  You should just import JRadioButton for the method I wrote.  Make sure you understand what import is doing.  It just saves keystrokes, nothing more.

Comment: I understand what imports do. Im just having hard time thinking about how to show array of buttons when a radio button is clicked.

Comment: Good luck - accept this answer if it helps.  I'm finished with your question, hard time or not.

Comment: @duffymo +1 maybe reason for implementing ButtonGroup

Comment: How can i close this question?

Comment: For additional question regarding the codes. For scenario, a radio button is clicked,which is 3x3 then 9 buttons will be shown in the output.if you click a button out of 9 buttons,a message box will appear'catch the mouse!' if you click on the button with x on it, the x will transfer to the other button randomly. Do i make sense here?just want to know if this is possible? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Put it in a class of your choosing and run it.

Comment: when i put this one,fatal error comes out and it doesn't even run.